# Pasar parámetros con tilde en URL en django rest framework | Python

Tags: python, url, djangorestframework

Estoy usando django rest framework para generar un archivo, tengo esta función en mi `views.py`:

```
def InformacionBibTex(request, bloque, idUsuario):
   print('BLOQUE', bloque)

   #...
   return response
```

Uso esta función para usarla en mi `urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = [
  path('informacion_bibtex/<slug:bloque>/<int:idUsuario>', views.InformacionBibTex),
]
```

En esta url paso como parámetros un `slug:bloque` y un `int:idUsuario` para poder usarlos en mi función.

Los parámetros los paso desde mi servicio frontend en Angular por medio de una petición `Get`:

```js
generaInformacionBibTex(bloque, id_user){
    const httpOptions = {
      responseType: 'blob' as 'json',
    };
    return this.http.get(this.url + 'informacion_bibtex/' + bloque + '/' + id_user, httpOptions);
  }
```

La URL que envio a mi servidor es esta:

```
http://localhost:8000/api/informacion_bibtex/ARTÍCULOS/127
```

El problema que tengo es que al hacer la petición al servidor me da el siguiente error

```
"GET /api/informacion_bibtex/ART%C3%8DCULOS/127 HTTP/1.1" 404 11500
```

Esto debido a la tilde que tiene `ARTÍCULOS`, el servidor me pone varios caracteres como porcentajes y números.

Lo mismo me pasa con los espacios:

```
"GET /api/informacion_bibtex/GRADO%20ACAD%C3%89MICO/127 HTTP/1.1" 404 11520
```

En este caso lo que envio es:

```
http://localhost:8000/api/informacion_bibtex/GRADO ACADÉMICO/127
```

Cómo puedo hacer para que el servidor me acepte la petición `Get` que hago desde mi frontend con parámetros que contengan tildes y espacios. Espero me puedan ayudar. Gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El URL dispatcher está esperando un [slug](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/urls/#path-converters) pero no lo está recibiendo. Un slug sólo permite letras ascii, números, guiones y guiones bajos, cualquier otra cosa no entrará en esa regla.

Puedes cambiar la definición de la URL para que reciba strings con:

```
urlpatterns = [
  path('informacion_bibtex/<str:bloque>/<int:idUsuario>', views.InformacionBibTex),
]
```

O, si quieres usar slugs y estás esperando acceder a un modelo por su nombre, utilizar slugify haciendo override del save del modelo.

Comment: Nota tiquismiquis. Donde dices "caracteres ascii" mejor decir "letras ascii", que es lo que realmente espera el slug. Porque lo que le estaba pasando el OP, al estar recodificado con url-encode, contenía también solo caracteres ascii, si bien uno de ellos (%) no era una letra ni numero

Comment: Toda la razón, edito para evitar la confusión

Comment: Me sirvió de mucho, Gracias!